# .NET control for spellchecking html files (.NET)?

Tags: .net, components, spell-checking

I would like to spell check html files programmatically using C#? The text only without the tags.

Any recommendations? Please mention ones that strip out the tags.

Comment: Use the HTML Agility Pack in combination with a spell checker library.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the text from HTML use the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). There has also been some open source work for HTML spell checking on Codeplex: see the [Spello](http://spello.codeplex.com/) project.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you you strip all tags first then spell check the resulting text. That's what is done inweb based wysiwyg html editors.

To strip html tags:http://en.csharp-online.net/Strip_all_HTML_tags